# Why does my Python "if-else" block not produce the same result as two if statements with the same logic?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a puzzle to solve. There have 2 variables; fr and d.

fr is a list of strings and d is a dictionary with email addresses as keys and numbers as values (numbers in string format).

I need to write code to replace the email address in each of the strings in the fr list with
the associated value of that email looked up from the dictionary d.

If the dictionary does not contain the email found in the list, add a new entry
in the dictionary for the email found in the fr list. The value for this new email key
will be the next highest value number in the dictionary in string format.

Once the dictionary is populated with this new email key and a new number value,
replace that email's occurrence in the fr list with the number value.

Here is the original fr list and d dictionary:

```py
    fr = [
    '7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV',
    '7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV',
    '13@comp1.COM|12|82|GDSPV',
    '26@comp1.COM|19|82|GDSPV',
    '39@stanford.COM|39|82|GIBBO'
    ]
    
    d= {
    '7@comp1.COM': '199',
    '8@comp4.COM': '200',
    '13@comp1.COM': '205'
    }


Here is the first version of my code with two dislodged if statements. This produces the desired results:


    new_list = []
    
    # looping through the fr list items
    for item in fr:
        fr_email = item[ : item.find('|')]  # find the email fr portion
        fr_back = item[item.find('|') :]  # find the back fr portion
    
    # add new key value pair to d - DICTIONARY
    if d.get(fr_email) is None:
        d[fr_email] = str(int(max(d.values())) + 1)
    
    # change the new list to dict value - LIST
    if d.get(fr_email) is not None:
        new_list.append(str(d.get(fr_email)) + fr_back)
    
    fr = new_list # so we don't change the looped list directly

    # prints results:
    # --------------------------------------
    print("Value of fr: ")
    print(fr)
    print("Value of d:")
    print(d)

This is the results for version 1 of my code (two dislodged if-statements):
--------------------------------------
Value of fr: 
['199|4|11|GDSPV', '199|16|82|GDSPV', '205|12|82|GDSPV', '206|19|82|GDSPV', '207|39|82|GIBBO']

Value of d:
{'7@comp1.COM': '199', '8@comp4.COM': '200', '13@comp1.COM': '205', '26@comp1.COM': '206', #'39@stanford.COM': '207'}

This is version 2 of the if statement block (with an else included). The rest remains the same as above.

    
    if d.get(fr_email) is None: # add new key value pair to d - DICTIONARY
        d[fr_email] = str(int(max(d.values())) + 1)
    else: # otherwise add to empty list
        new_list.append(str(d.get(fr_email)) + fr_back)
    
   
Here are the incorrect results, based on the second version. There are fewer list items returned (Value of fr)
--------------------------------------
Value of fr: 
['199|4|11|GDSPV', '199|16|82|GDSPV', '205|12|82|GDSPV']

Value of d:
{'7@comp1.COM': '199', '8@comp4.COM': '200', '13@comp1.COM': '205', '26@comp1.COM': '206', '39@stanford.COM': '207'}
```

Comment: "So we don't change the looped list directly" `fr = new_list` does not make  copy of `new_list`; it just makes a new name for the same list. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: When the code `d[fr_email] = str(int(max(d.values())) + 1)` in the first `if` block runs, what effect do you think that will have on the result of `d.get(fr_email)`? Why? Do you see why that matters to the `if`/`else` logic?

Comment: If there are less items, it's because in the IF clause, there is no "append" method. The list is only updated if the string is already a key of the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1** Focusing on the `why are these 2 condition setups yielding different results`: in the *first* case:

- the 2 conditions are evaluated independently
- because the first one will create an entry when the key is not found, the second `if` will *always* be true

In the *second* case, the `else` will fire *only* if the first `if` is false (entry already exists).

Basically, your logic in both cases is equivalent, if not for the fact that **you're mutating the dictionary your conditional is inspecting** mid-way through.

More pythonically, to illustrate:

```
if val_A not in first_dict:
  first_dict[val_A] = "foo"

# this `if` is evaluating the `new` state of `first_dict` - changed by the rule above - so **it will always be true**
if val_A in first_dict:
  new_list.append("bar")
```

Which would be functionally equivalent to:

```
if val_A not in first_dict:
  first_dict[val_A] = "foo"

# since the previous `if` was always true, just drop it and run the line unconditionally
new_list.append("bar")
```

**#2** RE the `challenge logic` try something like:

```
for line in email_marks_list:
  # extract email str from `line`
  if email_at_beginning in d:
    # replace email with d[email_at_beginning]
  else:
    # extract max_mark from `line`
    d[email_at_beginning] = max_mark
    line_idx = email_marks_list.index(line)
    email_marks_list[line_idx] = <replace first section of line with max_mark
```